# SQL Server job failing 10-20% of the time for "there is already an object named '##tmp_tbl' in the DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server 2008 job set to run every 15 minutes, calling a stored procedure. Normally this runs without issue, but lately it has been failing at random times throughout the day and causing issues with a report that is calling that stored procedure.

[image: Job history for this morning]

The original query has always contained a check to drop the table if exists

```
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl')) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl
```

I also tried creating a new procedure with the same parameters to test the query and changing it based on other questions I have seen here:

```
IF SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl
END
```

Or by changing all of the check's to:

```
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl')) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl
```

but all this did was kill the new test job I created, it now runs for an average of 45 minutes and fails almost every time (maybe I did it wrong? I made the change and hit execute, should I have disabled the job first?)

Does anyone know why this would fail 10-20% of the time for a `##tmp_tbl` when it runs fine most of the day?

Full code below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetGoaling_Outs]
    @site varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlStr nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @sqlStr2 nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @openQueryStr nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @so nvarchar(15)
    DECLARE @goalDate nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @wc nvarchar(35)
    DECLARE @wc2 nvarchar(35)
    DECLARE @goal_yield smallint
    DECLARE @early_goal_date nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @early_goal_yield smallint

     --Declare @site varchar(4)
     --set @site = 'OR01'
     --[sp_GetGoaling_Outs] 'OR01'

        --set @so = '147300'
        --set @goalDate = '2016/02/24'



IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl')) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl


IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM GoalTemp)  --If the Goal Temp Table is empty, then do not run
BEGIN

    TRUNCATE TABLE Goal
    INSERT INTO GOAL (shop_order,work_center, goal_yield, goal_date, early_goal_yield, early_goal_date)
        SELECT shop_order,work_center, goal_yield, goal_date, early_goal_yield, early_goal_date
        FROM GOALTemp



    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT shop_order, work_center, goal_date, goal_yield, early_goal_yield, early_goal_date
    FROM Goal
    --WHERE goal_date >  DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE())

    OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @so, @wc, @goalDate, @goal_yield, @early_goal_yield, @early_goal_date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  

    SET @wc2 = 'BDL_' + @wc
    ----------------------------------------GET Yield (Outs) for work center to current date AND to end goal date-------------------------------------- 

    set @sqlStr = 'SELECT site, shop_order, work_center, goal_date, wc_outs, 
            (SELECT WC_OUTS_TO_NEED_DATE
    FROM (
     --count the outs for the work center/max reporting operation seq
       SELECT DISTINCT  
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY shop_order, work_center ORDER BY shop_order )  WC_OUTS_TO_NEED_DATE
       FROM (
                SELECT *
               FROM (
                     --get the work center, reporting operation seq, and max reporting op seq for the route 
                     SELECT base.site, base.shop_order,base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, 
            base.completeDateTime ,base.operation, base.work_center, cf.value rep_op_seq
            , row_number() over (partition by base.shop_order, base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, base.operation, base.work_center order by base.shop_order) rownumber                                
            , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center ) AS max_wc_op_rpt_seq 
            , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center )+1 AS max_wc_op_rpt_seqPlus
            FROM (
                  --get only completes during the filtered time for the active shop orders
                  SELECT DISTINCT al.site, al.router, al.router_revision, al.sfc,
                  al.activity, al.reporting_center_bo
                  ,substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','')) shop_order 
                  ,(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 ) completeDateTime  
                  , substr(o.reporting_center_bo,instr(o.reporting_center_bo, '','') + 1,length(o.reporting_center_bo)) work_center
                  , o.handle oHandle
                  , o.operation 
                  FROM
                    wip.activity_log al,
                    wip.operation o
                  WHERE
                    al.action_code = ''COMPLETE''
                    AND al.operation = o.operation
                    AND al.site = ''' + @site + '''

                    AND trunc(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 )
                        <= TO_DATE(''' + @goalDate + ''',''yyyy/mm/dd'')

                    AND substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '',''))
                                    = ''' + @so + ''' 
              ) base
              ,wip.router r, wip.router_step rs, wip.router_operation ro
              ,(SELECT SUBSTR(handle,instr(handle, '','') + 1,length(handle) - instr(handle, '','') - 2) operation, attribute, value
                    FROM wip.custom_fields 
                    WHERE attribute = ''REPORT_OP_SEQUENCE'' ) cf
              WHERE   
              base.router = r.router (+)    
              AND base.router_revision = r.revision (+)          
              AND r.handle = rs.router_bo (+)
              AND rs.handle = ro.router_step_bo (+)
              AND substr( ro.operation_bo,1,length(ro.operation_bo)-2) =  substr( base.oHandle,1,length(base.oHandle)-2) 
              AND base.operation = cf.operation (+)
              AND base.work_center = ''' + @wc2 + '''
           )
            WHERE rownumber = 1
        )
      WHERE rep_op_seq = max_wc_op_rpt_seq
      ) ) WC_OUTS_TO_NEED_DATE '

    SET @sqlStr2 = ' FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT  site, shop_order
      , work_center, ''' + @goalDate + ''' as goal_date,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY shop_order, work_center ORDER BY shop_order )  WC_OUTS
      FROM (
                SELECT *
                 FROM (
                    --get the work center, reporting operation seq, and max reporting op seq for the route 
                    SELECT base.site, base.shop_order,base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, 
                    base.completeDateTime ,base.operation, base.work_center, cf.value rep_op_seq
                    , row_number() over (partition by base.shop_order, base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, base.operation, base.work_center order by base.shop_order) rownumber  
                    , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center ) AS max_wc_op_rpt_seq 
                    , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center )+1 AS max_wc_op_rpt_seqPlus
                    FROM (
                           --get only completes during the filtered time for the active shop orders
                           SELECT DISTINCT al.site, al.router, al.router_revision, al.sfc,
                          al.activity, al.reporting_center_bo
                                   ,substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','')) shop_order 
                                   ,(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 ) completeDateTime  
                           , substr(o.reporting_center_bo,instr(o.reporting_center_bo, '','') + 1,length(o.reporting_center_bo)) work_center
                         , o.handle oHandle
                         , o.operation                                        
                  FROM
                    wip.activity_log al,
                    wip.operation o
                  WHERE
                   al.action_code = ''COMPLETE''
                   AND al.operation = o.operation
                   AND al.site = ''' + @site + '''
                            --  AND trunc(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 )
                            --  <= TO_DATE(''' + @goalDate + ''',''yyyy/mm/dd'')

                    AND substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '',''))
                                    = ''' + @so + ''' 
              ) base
              ,wip.router r  , wip.router_step rs, wip.router_operation ro
              ,(SELECT SUBSTR(handle,instr(handle, '','') + 1,length(handle) - instr(handle, '','') - 2) operation, attribute, value
                    FROM wip.custom_fields 
                    WHERE attribute = ''REPORT_OP_SEQUENCE'' ) cf
              WHERE   
              base.router = r.router (+)    
              AND base.router_revision = r.revision (+)       
              AND r.handle = rs.router_bo (+)
              AND rs.handle = ro.router_step_bo (+)
              AND substr( ro.operation_bo,1,length(ro.operation_bo)-2) =  substr( base.oHandle,1,length(base.oHandle)-2) 
              AND base.operation = cf.operation (+)
              AND base.work_center  = ''' + @wc2 + '''
         )
                 WHERE rownumber = 1                          
       )
      WHERE rep_op_seq = max_wc_op_rpt_seq
    )'


             SET @openQueryStr = 'select * into ##tmp_tbl FROM OPENQUERY(WIP, ''' + REPLACE(@sqlStr, '''', '''''') + REPLACE(@sqlStr2, '''', '''''') + ''')' 
             EXEC(@openQueryStr)    
        --print  @sqlStr
        --print  @sqlStr2


                UPDATE goal
                SET actual_yield = t.wc_outs,
                actual_yield_to_need_date = t.WC_OUTS_TO_NEED_DATE
                FROM goal g inner join ##tmp_tbl t ON g.shop_order = t.shop_order
                    AND g.work_center = Right(t.work_center, LEN(t.work_center)-4)
                    AND g.goal_date = t.goal_date   





    ---------------------------IF THERE IS AN EARLY GOAL, THEN GET THE OUTS FOR THAT GOAL up to the early goal date--------------

    IF (@early_goal_date IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl


    set @sqlStr =  'SELECT DISTINCT  site, shop_order
    , work_center, ''' + @early_goal_date + ''' as goal_date,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY shop_order, work_center ORDER BY shop_order )  WC_OUTS
    FROM (
           SELECT *
           FROM (
                        SELECT base.site, base.shop_order, base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, 
                        base.completeDateTime ,base.operation, base.work_center, cf.value rep_op_seq
                        , row_number() over (partition by base.shop_order, base.sfc, base.router, base.router_revision, base.operation, base.work_center order by base.shop_order) rownumber                                    
                        , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center ) AS max_wc_op_rpt_seq 
                        , MAX(cf.value) OVER (PARTITION BY base.work_center )+1 AS max_wc_op_rpt_seqPlus
                         FROM (
                               SELECT DISTINCT al.site, al.router, al.router_revision, al.sfc, 
                               al.activity, al.reporting_center_bo
                                ,substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','')) shop_order 
                                ,(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 ) completeDateTime  
                        , substr(o.reporting_center_bo,instr(o.reporting_center_bo, '','') + 1,length(o.reporting_center_bo)) work_center
                        , o.handle oHandle
                        , o.operation 
                      FROM
                        wip.activity_log al,
                        wip.operation o
                      WHERE
                        al.action_code = ''COMPLETE''
                        AND al.operation = o.operation
                        AND al.site = ''' + @site + '''
                        AND trunc(al.date_time + to_number(concat(substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 1, 1), substr(extract(TIMEZONE_OFFSET from systimestamp), 12, 2))) / 24 )
                        <= TO_DATE(''' + @early_goal_date + ''',''yyyy/mm/dd'')

                      AND substr(al.shop_order_bo,instr( al.shop_order_bo, '','') + 1,length( al.shop_order_bo) - instr( al.shop_order_bo, '',''))
                                        = ''' + @so + ''' 
                  ) base
                  ,wip.router r  , wip.router_step rs  , wip.router_operation ro 
                  ,(SELECT SUBSTR(handle,instr(handle, '','') + 1,length(handle) - instr(handle, '','') - 2) operation, attribute, value
                        FROM wip.custom_fields 
                        WHERE attribute = ''REPORT_OP_SEQUENCE'' ) cf
                  WHERE   
                  base.router = r.router (+)    
                  AND base.router_revision = r.revision (+)    
                  AND r.handle = rs.router_bo (+)
                  AND rs.handle = ro.router_step_bo (+)
                  AND substr( ro.operation_bo,1,length(ro.operation_bo)-2) =  substr( base.oHandle,1,length(base.oHandle)-2) 
                  AND base.operation = cf.operation (+)
                  AND base.work_center = ''' + @wc2 + '''
            )
           WHERE rownumber = 1                                    
     )
    WHERE rep_op_seq = max_wc_op_rpt_seq
    ORDER BY shop_order, work_center'


             SET @openQueryStr = N'select * into ##tmp_tbl FROM OPENQUERY(WIP, ''' + REPLACE(@sqlStr, '''', '''''') + ''')' 
             EXEC(@openQueryStr)    
            --print @sqlStr

                UPDATE goal
                SET early_actual_yield_to_need_date = t.wc_outs
                FROM goal g inner join ##tmp_tbl t ON g.shop_order = t.shop_order
                    AND g.work_center = Right(t.work_center, LEN(t.work_center)-4)
                    AND g.early_goal_date = t.goal_date
            END
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                       




            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_tbl') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @so, @wc, @goalDate, @goal_yield, @early_goal_yield, @early_goal_date
    END  

    CLOSE db_cursor  
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

        END
    END



    --[sp_GetGoaling_Outs] 'OR01'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the "global" temp table vs the "local" temp table? If a job is scheduled to run every 15 minutes, and run for 45 minutes, with the involvement of a global temp table, too many things can go wrong (depends on the code calling it).

Comment: Does it run successfully when the job is off? I'd expect subsequent jobs to fail while one process is already using the ## table, I would switch to local temp unless there's a reason for global.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You may want to try adding another step ahead of this one to drop the objects out of the temp database first.

Comment: @DVT I took this over from someone who wrote most of the stored procedures, I am just learning this as I go. as far as I know there is no reason. do you think that would fix this issue?

Comment: @marc_s I did not know that, thanks for the info!

Comment: @HartCO I just tried that again, normally it ran for 2 1/2 minutes, its at 5 now so i'm guessing its a no it doesn't. which would make me think I need to restart SQL because somehow the temp tables are messed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want that table dropped before beginning the sp--

```
BEGIN TRY  
  drop table ##tmp_tbl
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
  /* table does not exist */
END CATCH
```

Comment: this ran successfully, but it took 45 minutes

Comment: It should buzz right through this piece.. how long does it take usually? Have you run this query through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor?

Comment: no i have not! I do not know what that is! the regular query runs in 2 minutes. the test one I made to make edits is taking that long with the only difference being adding/removing these queries on the page

Comment: Might be worth a look.. first run the query, then go to Query>Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor.. Follow the wizard to create constraints to boost a queries performance

Answer (score 1):

The name ##tmp_tbl is too generic for a Global Temp table, there is probably another process on the server that is using the same name and occasionally overlapping with your process.

Try renaming the ## table to something that is specific to your process

i.e ##tmp_sp_GetGoaling_Outs

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to use global temp table because you are creating it inside a dynamic sql. But I notice that you are creating and dropping the ##tmp_tbl **inside a cursor**. 
I would recommend that you create this global temp table **outside** of the cursor, such as the following

```
if object_id('tempdb..##temp_tbl') is not null
   drop table ##temp_tbl;

create table ##temp_tbl (....)
```

Inside your cursor, you need to re-write your dynamic query, instead of using

```
select .. into ##temp_tbl from ...
```

using

```
truncate table ##temp_tbl; 
insert into ##temp_tbl (...) 
select ... from
```

I suspect the error you see is probably inside the cursor when trying to do the select * into ##temp_tbl.

Comment: is there a specific way i should be editing this stored procedure to not mess up the job? IE stop job, update procedure, restart job. or since it runs every 15 min make the change in between runs?